# Hosting web application on Amazon AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, web-development-server

I am developing a web application locally. However, I would like to host the final product on an Amazon EC2 instance. I have moved my web application to the EC2 instance and am able to run the application; it's now listening on port 8081.

What I don't understand is how to allow users on the internet to access the web application running on port 8081 of the EC2 instance. I have tried redirecting the domain name to the IP address of the EC2 instance on the NameCheap DNS (where we bought the domain) to no avail. I suspect one of the things I need to do is set the permissions of the EC2 permission group but what should I set it to?

Help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: what is ur ec2 instance OS?

Comment: Can you hit the IP directly from your browser? Wondering if the problem is DNS or EC2.

Comment: The ec2 instance is: Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-5ec1673e

Comment: What am I expecting to see if I can successfully hit the IP from browser? It's definitely not working, I see The 35.163.43.63 page isn’t working. 35.163.43.63 didn’t send any data.

Comment: You need to allow 8081 port on ec2 security group which is attached to your instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a `nginx` server to proxy all request to the port 8081.

Read more information here: https://doesnotscale.com/deploying-node-js-with-pm2-and-nginx/

Comment: As an interim solution I have redirected port 8081 to 80 as suggested in that post. That seemed to be the simplest solution. In the future I will look into using nginx server.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, for a public web application you will want to run on a standard port (e.g. 80 or 443).  You could do that by just running your node app as a privileged user (required by most OS's to expose 80 or 443), but generally it's better to have a web server in front pass the traffic, treating your node app as an upstream server (even if it's on localhost).  NGinX is a good choice for this.

Regardless of what port you want to run it on, you'll need to update your EC2 security policy for that instance to allow traffic on that port (80, 443, 8081, whatever). You'll also need to make sure it's exposing a public IP address.  It's not a bad idea to assign it an Elastic IP, since you'll wnat it to have the same address across instance reboots.

Finally, depending on what AMI you're running from, there may be a host firewall configured that you'll need to check on and configure to allow the traffic.